LibreSpot on parent network
I have an issue of getting Spotify Connect discoverable in my local network.
I am pretty sure it is an issue with multicast but I struggle to find out how to get this working.
I have LibreSpot running on my Raspberry Pi (and my speakers are connected to it). It is connected via wired connection to a local (not wireless) router (Router A) that provides internet connection. This Router A is also connected via wired connection to a (wireless) Router B.
Most of my local devices (my phone, laptop etc.) are connected to Router B. The issue is that these devices cannot see the librespot service in Spotify (neither on my phone or my laptop).
I used to find the librespot device the way that I provided my username and password directly to librespot and then it was discoverable on my phone but support for this was deprecated and I cannot use this anymore. The proper solution is to let the librespot authenticate via the client through zeroconf.
Router A subnetwork is 192.168.88.XXX and Router B subnet is 192.168.1.XXX.
Librespot's zeroconf server is running on 192.168.88.226 and port 37901.
This is definitely running since when I run this URL in the browser it provides basic information:
{
accountReq: "PREMIUM",
activeUser: "",
availability: "",
brandDisplayName: "librespot",
clientID: "[id]",
deviceID: "[id]",
deviceType: "Speaker",
groupStatus: "NONE",
libraryVersion: "0.5.0",
modelDisplayName: "librespot",
productID: 0,
publicKey: "[redacted]",
remoteName: "RPi",
resolverVersion: "1",
scope: "streaming",
spotifyError: 0,
status: 101,
statusString: "OK",
supported_capabilities: 1,
supported_drm_media_formats: [ ],
tokenType: "default",
version: "2.9.0"
}

So I think it is a multicast issue and that it is not broadcasted properly to the subnetwork of Router B. I believe that if I connected my Pi to the Router B it would work OK but I would prefer keeping my network as is.
I don't know how to debug this or even fix it.
Do I need to set up Router B in some way to forward the zeroconf multicast?
Do I need to set up LibreSpot differently?
Thanks for any guidance.

mDNS ("zeroconf") uses link-local multicast. Its packets will never cross routers, whether the router has multicast routing enabled or not.
To make this work you would need an mDNS proxy running on router B (or possibly on some other device that is connected on both networks). Recent RouterOS versions have a built-in mDNS proxy; Linux devices can run avahi-daemon in "reflector" mode.

Awesome, exactly the guidance I needed! Thanks a lot, I think the ASUS router I have runs some linux distro so I'll try sshing into it and run the avahi-daemon. Thank you!

It works by the way - there is an avahi-daemon already running so just adding the reflector config did the trick.
Just need to find a way how to ensure that the config is not overwritten on router reset as it seems to write that config into /tmp folder and it restores to default on avahi service restart
